# Cakephp + ckfinder Sessions don't seem to work

Tags: cakephp, cookies, session

I'm implementing ckfinder on a cakephp dev, I'm having problems with the ckfinder in which you need to have some kind of auth passing a session. But the sessions that I assign don't seem to be working on the config file or cookies.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Be sure that is php who stores session data. In your core.php:

```
Configure::write('Session.save', 'php');
```

If you let 'cake' to store session data external php files will not retrieve it. Also, remember to set the right name for session:

```
session_name("CAKEPHP");
```

Answer (score 0):

start the session with session_start();
and maybe need to match cookie domain with

```
ini_set('session.cookie_domain', 'example.net');
```

Answer (score 0):

it pretty simple and easy. open app\webroot\js\ckfinder\config.php. put the following codes there

```
session_name("CAKEPHP");
session_start();
```

Assuming in your config.php

```
Configure::write('Session.cookie', 'CAKEPHP');
```

I have written extensive tutorial for ckfinder and ckeditor. You can see here 
http://blog.jambura.com/2011/01/29/implementing-ckfinder-in-cakephp-1-3-with-authentication/